# The maximum number of subscribers returned through this API might be limited

Tags: youtube-data-api

[This](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list) document of youtube data api subscribers says that 'Note that the maximum number of subscribers returned through this API might be limited.'
Is there a way to get all subscribers?

As the document stated when I try this code, it returns small amount of all records.

```py
all_items = set()

next_page_token = ''

while True:
  request = youtube.subscriptions().list(
      part="subscriberSnippet, snippet",
      myRecentSubscribers=True,
      maxResults=50,
      pageToken=next_page_token
  )

  response = request.execute()
  print(response)
  for item in response['items']:
    all_items.add((item['id'], item['subscriberSnippet']['channelId'], item['subscriberSnippet']['title'], item['subscriberSnippet']['description'], item['snippet']['publishedAt']))

  if 'nextPageToken' in response:
    next_page_token = response['nextPageToken']
  else: break
```